# wxToolBar: get position and size of a tool?

Tags: c++, drop-down-menu, toolbar, wxwidgets

I have a wxToolBar with a drop-down item inside:

```
g_toolBar1->AddTool(TOOLBAR_CMD_CONTROL_DROPDOWN,_("Control elements"),MainWin::getBitmap(gearsXPM,"gears"),wxNullBitmap,wxITEM_DROPDOWN);
custParent->Connect(TOOLBAR_CMD_CONTROL_DROPDOWN,wxEVT_COMMAND_TOOL_CLICKED,wxCommandEventHandler(DrawCanvasSwitcher::OnToolbar),NULL,g_drawCanvas);
.... // add items to controlMenu here
g_toolBar1->SetDropdownMenu(TOOLBAR_CMD_CONTROL_DROPDOWN,controlMenu);
```

Under some conditions I open the drop-down menu programmatically by calling PopupMenu(). My problem here: this function opens the menu at the current mouse position, not below of the tool like the button with the down-arrow does it.

So: how can I get the position and the size of my tool TOOLBAR_CMD_CONTROL_DROPDOWN in order to calculate a suitable position for the drop-down menu in order to hand it over to PopupMenu()?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the `wxComboBox` class? If so: try `controlMenu.Popup()` ([see here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_combo_box.html#a325d7d2afc9e1e17f7b5fb13f4186d0c)) instead of `PopupMenu(controlMenu)`. Is that working as you expected?

Comment: Andre Kampling: no, no wxComboBox but a wxMenu used within a wxToolBar to create a drop-down tool

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call [`GetBestSize()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a7e64b9380374e5681f146e9e319e35e3) as I did below, also don't forget to call [`Realize()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_tool_bar.html#abb31ce337a2d3c1e30e8e3748905ecbf) after adding tools with [`AddTool()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_tool_bar.html#acd25fec352f66fb174f7f81a7d834b21).

```
g_toolBar1->AddTool(TOOLBAR_CMD_CONTROL_DROPDOWN,_("Control elements"),MainWin::getBitmap(gearsXPM,"gears"),wxNullBitmap,wxITEM_DROPDOWN);

/* Added the next two lines. */
g_toolBar1->Realize();
wxSize toolBarPos = g_toolBar1->GetBestSize();

/* If you add more tools call Realize() after that again. */
custParent->Connect(TOOLBAR_CMD_CONTROL_DROPDOWN,wxEVT_COMMAND_TOOL_CLICKED,wxCommandEventHandler(DrawCanvasSwitcher::OnToolbar),NULL,g_drawCanvas);
.... // add items to controlMenu here
g_toolBar1->SetDropdownMenu(TOOLBAR_CMD_CONTROL_DROPDOWN,controlMenu);
```

Then you can use the `toolBarPos` to call the [`PopupMenu()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a834bcdfd41f5e5370ebd9ea401c92900) method like:

```
PopupMenu(controlMenu, toolBarPos.getWidth(), toolBarPos.getHeight());
```

Comment: OK, but this gives me the position of the toolbar, not the position of the particular tool TOOLBAR_CMD_CONTROL_DROPDOWN where the drop-down menau should appear at!?

Comment: I'm not sure about that because I can't test it quickly as I'm not currently having wxWidgets installed. So please test it and report.

Comment: @Elmi: Could you post your answer and accept that solution so that other people can profit from it?

Comment: my solution is something completelydifferent whichhasnothing to do with wxToolbars....